# Compiling Eclipse project without Eclipse after finishing

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, rest, jersey

I have two questions:

Background: I am trying to create a RESTful Java API for Java back end server which I have already finished.

1) Researched online, and the best way to do this by using Eclipse, is it possible to create a  RESTful Java API (using Jersey) without having to use Eclipse? If so how?

2) Let's say I do use Eclipse. After completion, can I transfer the project to a Linux machine and run it there? (if it doesn't have Eclipse). My Linux machine will be the main host, I'm currently working on a windows machine.

Any feedback on this will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Use a build tool (ant, maven, gradle,etc).   Investigate the concepts of [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).  What you are describing goes beyond the intentions of IDEs such as Eclipse.

Comment: Also look at Export > Java > JAR file or Runnable JAR file